# Insert either HTML data or query results in to new table

Tags: php, mysql

I have possibly two questions. The first question I think I know the answer to but Im going to ask it anyways just incase Im missing something obvious.

1. Can you insert data from an HTML  row in to a db table? See below:

   ```
   <tr><td>Colby (Big Cheese)</td>
             <td>1A</td>
             <td>
             <select width=200>
             <option>Key Movement</option>
             <option>Movement -1</option>
             <option>Movement -2</option>
             <option>Movement -3</option>
             <option>Movement -4</option>
       </select></td>
       <td>Sets/Reps/Seconds</td>
       <td>Rest</td>
       <td>00</td>
       </tr><tr><td>Mike (Big Mac)</td>
             <td>1A</td>
             <td>
             <select width=200>
             <option>Key Movement</option>
             <option>Movement -1</option>
             <option>Movement -2</option>
             <option>Movement -3</option>
             <option>Movement -4</option>
       </select></td>
       <td>Sets/Reps/Seconds</td>
       <td>Rest</td>
       <td>00</td>
       </tr>
   ```

I want the data from each table row written to a row in the db. If the answer is no I will move to my 2nd question.

Here is my EDITED array that outputs this HTML.

```
    $count;
if(empty($workout_class) === false)
{   
foreach($workout_class as $wc){
if ($wc['pagenum'] !== $pagenum) continue 1;

    echo '<tr>
        <td name="first_name'.$count.'">'. ($wc['first_name']).' 
        <span name="nickname'.$count.'">('. ($wc['nickname']).')</span>
        </td>
              <td name="order'.$count.'">'. ($wc['order']). '</td>
              <td>
              <select name="movement'.$count.'" width=200>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_00']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_01']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_02']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_03']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_04']). '</option>
        </select></td>
        <td name="rep_set_sec'.$count.'">'. ($wc['rep_set_sec']). '</td>
        <td name="rest'.$count.'">'. ($wc['rest']). '</td>
        <td>00</td>
        </tr>';
        $count++;

   } // foreach($data_array
```

Couple of problems Im having. The `$_POST` is not picking up any of the data from the "name" values. It also only loop through the first row and stops. Any ideas.

Comment: Yes. Yes you can. [What have **you** tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I think I may have been making this harder than it is. I have been trying to assemble different querys and joins trying to get all the info I need. Can I put my table inside of a form?

Comment: That is absolutely valid HTML, yes. But if you're using javascript to pull the data and submit to an AJAX call, it's not necessary. Just grab the contents of each row and pass it to your script which will then loop through the data and insert it into your DB.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a server-side (PHP,ASP,JSP) language to do this via either a form (GET, POST) or JQuery/Ajax. You already have your select inputs so it will be fairly easy to implement once the Database and serverside language is set up.

```
<?php
$km1 = $_POST['key_move1'];
$km2 = $_POST['key_move2'];
/*
Your mysql code to enter $km1 and $km2 into the database
*/
echo $km1 . " -- " . $km2 . " <-  ...  Thos are your values that would pass to database";
?>

<form action="#" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>Colby (Big Cheese)</td>
      <td>1A</td>
      <td>
      <select name="key_move1" width=200>
      <option>Key Movement</option>
      <option>Movement -1</option>
      <option>Movement -2</option>
      <option>Movement -3</option>
      <option>Movement -4</option>
</select></td>
<td>Sets/Reps/Seconds</td>
<td>Rest</td>
<td>00</td>
</tr><tr><td>Mike (Big Mac)</td>
      <td>1A</td>
      <td>
      <select name="key_move2" width=200>
      <option>Key Movement</option>
      <option>Movement -1</option>
      <option>Movement -2</option>
      <option>Movement -3</option>
      <option>Movement -4</option>
</select></td>
<td>Sets/Reps/Seconds</td>
<td>Rest</td>
<td>00</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Go!">
```

php loop:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($workout_class as $wc){
if ($wc['pagenum'] !== $pagenum) continue 1;

echo '<tr><td>'. ($wc['first_name']).' ('. ($wc['nickname']).')</td>
          <td>'. ($wc['order']). '</td>
          <td>
          <select name="key_move' . $count . '" width=200>
          <option>'. ($wc['mv_00']). '</option>
          <option>'. ($wc['mv_01']). '</option>
          <option>'. ($wc['mv_02']). '</option>
          <option>'. ($wc['mv_03']). '</option>
          <option>'. ($wc['mv_04']). '</option>
    </select></td>
    <td>'. ($wc['rep_set_sec']). '</td>
    <td>'. ($wc['rest']). '</td>
    <td>00</td>
    </tr>';
$count++
}
```

Comment: I am using PHP but I was not aware that I could post table data to a db. Thought it would have to be done through a form so I have been trying to get querys and joins of what all I need and post to db that way...which was not working

Comment: This my create another problem. This html is created from a PHP array from a query. So the "name" would be the same for each row. So could I just do `name = key_move[]` so that it would loop through each result and start new db row when it starts a new table row?

Comment: You will need to use a counter or something to append the name ...  So you could use `$count = 0;` at the top.  Just inside your loop at the bottom of it, use `$count++;`.  Then when naming your fields, you can name them like `<select name="<?php echo key_move[$count] . $count; ?>" width="200">`  That will give you unique names for each field.

Comment: I posted my php array above so you can see what Im working with

Comment: would using $count++ increase the column/field name by 1....So first loop it puts the data in a column named keymove0 and then second loop would put data in a column named keymove1 instead of putting all the values in column "keymove" just on separate rows.

Comment: If I understand you correctly; I think you are looking at it a little skewed.  Each `<select>` input in HTML can only return a single value or `<option>` unless it's multiselect, which yours is not.  That being said, you will need to take key_move1, key_move2, key_move3 etc ..  and in your SQL apply them all to the same column, just in different rows.  So you would foreach key_move (You would get a $_POST count to determine this number), you would `INSERT INTO blah (key_row) VALUES('key_move_value')`  ..  I hope I am getting what you are looking for correct?

Comment: I think I was just getting confused as to what the $count++ was doing. I was thinking that `name = key_move . $count .` would cause php/mysql to be looking for columns in my db named `key_move0` , `key_move1` , `key_move2` etc....

Comment: I have edited my query about and posted a couple of problems Im having. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Like Zak mentioned, you will need to place this table inside of a form and submit, then process server side (PHP)... or have JavaScript get the values and submit to a server side script via AJAX. Either way, you will have to have a script server side that fetches these values, builds a query and makes a DB entry.

As a side note, you will probably want to create id elements for each HTML component so that you can easily retrieve these values from a POST, like so...

```
<select id="colby" name="colby" width=200>
```